# Image not showing when passed as an intent extra

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm trying to pass the screenshot of screen with an explicit intent but the screen shows black screenshot(refer image [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BztFESDzrNQjaDJRMWE5eHcxRXc)). As soon as i click share, a toast appears saying sending failed. Here's the code to capture screenshot and send it to other app:

```
public void getScreenShot(View view) {
        View screenView = view.getRootView();
        screenView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(screenView.getDrawingCache());
        screenView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
        f = new File(this.getFilesDir(), "screenshotFile");
        try {
            if (!f.exists())
                f.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOexception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 10, bos);
        byte[] bitmapdata = bos.toByteArray();

        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        try {
            fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
            fos.write(bitmapdata);
            fos.flush();
            fos.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

This code sends the data to whatsapp:

```
public void shareWhatsapp(View view) {
    try {
        myVib.vibrate(50);
        getScreenShot(view);

        //String fileName = "screenshotFile";
        //Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.getAbsolutePath());

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.setType("image/*");
        try {
            intent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "App not installed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        //TODO: APP CAN CRASH HERE
        if (position > 0) {
            try {
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(f);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Titles.get(position - 1) + ": " + Links.get(position - 1));       //position problems
            }
        } else {
            try {
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(f);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Titles.get(0) + ": " + Links.get(0));       //position problems
            }
        }
        startActivity(intent);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: which version of Android are you testing this on?

Comment: Android 6.0 MarshMallow

Comment: Maybe the downvoter can help, as he might be having too much free time not to read the entire problem.

Answer (score 0):

First, you are writing the file to [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html). Third-party apps do not have access to your app's internal storage.

Second, you are using `Uri.fromFile()`, which is [starting to be discontinued](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/03/14/psa-file-scheme-ban-n-developer-preview.html).

Your safest long-term course of action is to [have a `ContentProvider` serve your file from its location on internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/03/16/how-publish-files-via-content-uri.html), then use a `Uri` associated with that `ContentProvider`.

Comment: Tried using saving to external storage but still the save problem. Cant access the file. All permissions mentioned in manifest.
java.io.filenotfoundexception open failed eacces (permission denied)